# Не создается attribute в Magento

Tags: php, magento, атрибуты

Как можно создать свой новый атрибут и поместить его в `Default attribute set` и при этом в свою же новою групу?

Делаю это так (сначала просто хочу поместить в `Default` в любую групу):

```
<?php
/** @var Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup $this*/
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$data= array (
    'attribute_set' =>  'Default',
    'group' => 'General',
    'label'    => 'New Attr',
    'visible'     => true,
    'type'     => 'int', // multiselect uses comma-sep storage
    'input'    => 'boolean',
    'system'   => false,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,//defaults to false; if true, define a group
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'default' => 1,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
);


$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
$attributeSetId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
$installer->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General', 'new_attr', 10);

$installer->endSetup();
```

**Что я делаю не правильно ?**

Когда я перезагружаю страницу  она просто не загружается -  выдает

> Страница project.dev не работает

И при этом в `core_resource` таблицу не записываеться мой `setup`!

**Подскажите как это сделать правильно ? Или где я допустил ошибку ?**

Comment: что в логах ошибок?

Comment: @Naumov, в том и проблема, что в var/report/ ничего не кидает и в var/log/ тоже гичего нет!

Comment: что за сервер включи все ошибки? кэш отключён?

Comment: @Naumov, сервер Apache2, кэш отключён! И в самой magento включил логи

Comment: покажи `config.xml` и пути до файлов укажи, может ошибка в том что magento до install скрипта недоходит/

Comment: @Naumov, инстал скрипт выполняется, я тестировал - создавал новый attribute set , и все работало !

Comment: @Naumov, мой config.xml -  http://pastebin.com/qZTAaZj4